# SSL not resolving in IIS with Let's Encrypt

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8, lets-encrypt

I have successfully created a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate using [Lone-Coder's Windows Sample](https://github.com/Lone-Coder/letsencrypt-win-simple)

- The SSL certificate has been installed and appears in IIS under Server Certificates.
- A `HTTPS` binding was successfully associated with my site in IIS.
- The StaticFile handler mapping is being executed before the ExtensionLess URL Mapper.

When I visit my domain: https://subdomain1.mysite.com I am getting a site not found.

**Further information:**
I have three sites on this server:

- subdomain1.mysite.com (this one has the Let's Encrypt SSL applied)
- subdomain2.mysite.com
- www.mysite.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting and manually adding the binding again. Sometimes it can get miss configured.

Check firewalls.

Comment: It turned out to be port 443 not being open in my cloud environment (Azure).